# I put an image in the center but it shows it on the right

Tags: ios, xcode, image

I put an image in the center but when I run it, it shows it on the right. I tried "Mode:Center" but still on the right. Does anybody know why?

Comment: Oh, we need more informations from you. Can you post your code or have you set the image via interface builder?

Comment: I set it via  interface builder..

Comment: The other thing is, in Interface builder >> Size inspector .. everything is locked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add constraints to your Image. You do that by leftclicking on the image in interface builder. After you selected the image you go to the bottom right corner of interface builder and click on the little triangle. Left click it, then left click "Add missing constraints" 
Hope it helps

Comment: It worked, thank you! :)

Comment: you are very welcome :)